# weex.js - how to pass the loop variable into event handler

Tags: javascript, weex

I'm running this code:

```
<template>
    <div>
        <text onclick="log(items[0])">outside the loop</text>
        <div repeat="item in items">
            <text onclick="log(item)">{{item}}</text>
        </div>
    </div>
</template>
<script>
    module.exports = {
        data: {
            items: ['foo']
        },
        methods: {
            log: function(item) {
                console.log(item);
            }
        }
    }
</script>
```

When I click the "outside the lop", I see `foo`, but when I click the "foo", I see `undefined`. How could I pass the loop variable into the event handler?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This demo is ok in native code environment(I test it using iOS WeexSDK).
Maybe it is a bug in browser.

By the way, you can use vuejs grammar in latest WeexSDK and it's no problem with loop variable.

demo: http://dotwe.org/vue/658afd881a720ab0c877a5bb2d88b9f4

Answer (score 0):

Use $index variable available in the loop scope:

```
<div repeat="item in items">
  <text onclick="log(items[$index])">{{item}}</text>
</div>
```

Comment: I see `undefined` this way. Actually I see `undefined`  even with `log($index)`

Answer (score 0):

if i use vue

```
<template>
    <div>
        <text @click="log(items[0],$event)">outside the loop</text>
        <div v-for="item in items">
            <text @click="log(item,$event)">{{item}}</text>
        </div>
    </div>
    </template>
    <script>
    module.exports = {
        data: {
            items: ['foo']
        },
        methods: {
            log: function(item,e) {
                console.log(item);
            }
        }
    }
    </script>
```